# Windows VPN and SSO

Tags: windows, vpn

I have an ipsec tunnel from Network A (my domain) to Network B (other domain).

User in Network B can connect with systems in network A providing AD credentials.

But the problem is that they have to enter the credentials each time (they are continuity asking for credentials)... There is no SSO I think because the computers are outside of the domain.

What can I do? I want the user from a external domain can connect to my systems using SSO.
I want to do it in a secure way, I read about Credential Manager but I think is not secure.

Comment: Maybe creating a trust between these domains could work https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc757352%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using a VPN does not change the essence of the problem.

If by "connect" you mean "connect to a share", the non-domain user can use `net use` to store his credentials (and also probably assign a letter to the share to have it handy). See `net use /?` for the command details.

In the user is in its own domain then you could [setting a trust between the domains](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770299.aspx).